# Why am I getting a syntax error for this declaring this array?

Tags: python, neural-network

Here is the specific line the error occurred: (@ line 146)
d_hi1_d_w = []

"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

This is the main method for a neural net for a program with 3 inputs, two hidden lays of 5 neurons each and a single output.

h1 represents neurons in the first layer
hi1 represents neurons in the second layer

feedforward and feedforward2 apply weights and biases feedforward returns an array of values for the first layer while feedforward 2 returns a singular output value

****** IN THE UPDATE WEIGHTS AND BIASES PORTION I STILL NEED TO UPDATE NEURONS H3 TO H5 AND NEURONS HI1 TO HI5 AS WELL AS O1 ******

Here is the error in train method:

```
import numpy as np


    def train(self, data, all_y_trues):
        '''
        - data is a (n x 3) numpy array, n = # of samples in the dataset.
        - all_y_trues is a numpy array with n elements.
          Elements in all_y_trues correspond to those in data.
        '''
        learn_rate = 0.1
        epochs = 1000 # number of times to loop through the entire dataset

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            for x, y_true in zip(data, all_y_trues):
                # --- Do a feedforward (we'll need these values later)

                h1 = sigmoid(np.dot(x, self.wforh1) + self.b1)
                h2 = sigmoid(np.dot(x, self.wforh2) + self.b2)
                h3 = sigmoid(np.dot(x, self.wforh3) + self.b3)
                h4 = sigmoid(np.dot(x, self.wforh4) + self.b4)
                h5 = sigmoid(np.dot(x, self.wforh5) + self.b5)

                sum_h1 = np.dot(x, self.wforh1) + self.b1
                sum_h2 = np.dot(x, self.wforh2) + self.b2
                sum_h3 = np.dot(x, self.wforh3) + self.b3
                sum_h4 = np.dot(x, self.wforh4) + self.b4
                sum_h5 = np.dot(x, self.wforh5) + self.b5

                y = self.feedforward(x)

                hi1 = sigmoid(np.dot(y, self.wforhi1) + self.b6)
                hi2 = sigmoid(np.dot(y, self.wforhi2) + self.b7)
                hi3 = sigmoid(np.dot(y, self.wforhi3) + self.b8)
                hi4 = sigmoid(np.dot(y, self.wforhi4) + self.b9)
                hi5 = sigmoid(np.dot(y, self.wforhi5) + self.b10)

                sum_hi1 = np.dot(y, self.wforhi1) + self.b6
                sum_hi2 = np.dot(y, self.wforhi2) + self.b7
                sum_hi3 = np.dot(y, self.wforhi3) + self.b8
                sum_hi4 = np.dot(y, self.wforhi4) + self.b9
                sum_hi5 = np.dot(y, self.wforhi5) + self.b10
                z = np.array([hi1,hi2,hi3,hi4,hi5])
                h = np.array([h1,h2,h3,h4,h5])


                o1 = self.feedforward2(y)
                sum_o1 = np.dot(z, self.wforo1) + self.b11 
                y_pred = o1

                # --- Calculate partial derivatives.
                # --- Naming: d_L_d_w1 represents "partial L / partial w1"
                d_L_d_ypred = -2 * (y_true - y_pred)



                # Neuron o1 NEW
                d_ypred_d_w = []
                for i in range(5):
                    d_ypred_d_w.append(z[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1))
                #d_ypred_d_w41 = hi1 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)
                #d_ypred_d_w42 = hi2 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)
                #d_ypred_d_w43 = hi3 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)
                #d_ypred_d_w44 = hi4 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)
                #d_ypred_d_w45 = hi5 * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)
                d_ypred_d_b11 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1)

                d_ypred_d_hi = []
                for i in range(5):
                    d_ypred_d_hi.append(self.wforo1[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1))
                d_ypred_d_h = []
                for i in range(5):
                     d_ypred_d_h.append(deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1) * (self.wforo1[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1) * self.wforhi1[i] + self.wforo1[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2) * self.wforhi2[i] + self.wforo1[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3) * self.wforhi3[i] + self.wforo1[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4) * self.wforhi4[i] + self.wforo1[4] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5) * self.wforhi5[i])
                #d_ypred_d_h1 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1) * (self.wforo1[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1) * self.wforhi1[0] + self.wforo1[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2) * self.wforhi2[0] + self.wforo1[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3) * self.wforhi3[0] + self.wforo1[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4) * self.wforhi4[0] + self.wforo1[4] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5) * self.wforhi5[0])               
                #d_ypred_d_h2 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1) * (self.wforo1[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1) * self.wforhi1[1] + self.wforo1[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2) * self.wforhi2[1] + self.wforo1[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3) * self.wforhi3[1] + self.wforo1[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4) * self.wforhi4[1] + self.wforo1[4] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5) * self.wforhi5[1])
                #d_ypred_d_h3 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1) * (self.wforo1[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1) * self.wforhi1[2] + self.wforo1[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2) * self.wforhi2[2] + self.wforo1[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3) * self.wforhi3[2] + self.wforo1[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4) * self.wforhi4[2] + self.wforo1[4] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5) * self.wforhi5[2])
                #d_ypred_d_h4 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1) * (self.wforo1[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1) * self.wforhi1[3] + self.wforo1[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2) * self.wforhi2[3] + self.wforo1[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3) * self.wforhi3[3] + self.wforo1[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4) * self.wforhi4[3] + self.wforo1[4] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5) * self.wforhi5[3])
                #d_ypred_d_h5 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1) * (self.wforo1[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1) * self.wforhi1[4] + self.wforo1[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2) * self.wforhi2[4] + self.wforo1[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3) * self.wforhi3[4] + self.wforo1[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4) * self.wforhi4[4] + self.wforo1[4] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5) * self.wforhi5[4])



                # Neuron hi1 NEW

                d_hi1_d_w = []
                for i in range(5):
                    d_hi1_d_w.append(h[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1))
                d_hi1_d_b6 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1)

                # Neuron hi2 NEW
                d_hi2_d_w = []
                for i in range(5):
                    d_hi2_d_w.append(h[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2))
                d_hi2_d_b7 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2)

                # Neuron hi3 NEW
                d_hi3_d_w = []
                for i in range(5):
                    d_hi3_d_w.append(h[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3))
                d_hi3_d_b8 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3)

                # Neuron hi4 NEW
                d_hi4_d_w = []
                for i in range(5):
                    d_hi4_d_w.append(h[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4))
                d_hi4_d_b9 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4)

                #Neuron hi5 NEW
                d_hi5_d_w = []
                for i in range(5):
                    d_hi5_d_w.append(h[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5))
                d_hi5_d_b10 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5)

                #Neuron h1 NEW
                d_h1_d_w = []
                for i in range(3):
                    d_h1_d_w.append(x[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h1))
                d_h1_d_b1 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_h1)

                #Neuron h2 NEW
                d_h2_d_w = []
                for i in range(3):
                    d_h2_d_w.append(x[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h2))
                d_h2_d_b2 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_h2)

                #Neuron h3 NEW
                d_h3_d_w = []
                for i in range(3):
                    d_h3_d_w.append(x[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h3))
                d_h3_d_b3 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_h3)

                #Neuron h4 NEW
                d_h4_d_w = []
                for i in range(3):
                    d_h4_d_w.append(x[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h4))
                d_h4_d_b4 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_h4)

                #Neuron h5 NEW
                d_h5_d_w = []
                for i in range(3):
                    d_h5_d_w.append(x[i] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_h5))
                d_h5_d_b5 = deriv_sigmoid(sum_h5)



                # --- Update weights and biases
                # Neuron h1
                for i in range(3):
                    self.wforh1[i] = self.wforh1[i]- learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h[0] * d_h1_d_w[i]
                self.b1 = self.b1 - learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h[0] * d_h1_d_b1

                # Neuron h2
                for i in range(3):
                    self.wforh2[i] = self.wforh2[i] - learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h[1] * d_h2_d_w[i]
                self.b2 = self.b2 - learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h[1] * d_h2_d_b2

                # Neuron h3

                self.w7 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h3 * d_h3_d_w7
                self.w8 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h3 * d_h3_d_w8
                self.w9 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h3 * d_h3_d_w9
                self.b3 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h3 * d_h3_d_b3

                # Neuron h4
                self.w10 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h4 * d_h4_d_w10
                self.w11 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h4 * d_h4_d_w11
                self.w12 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h4 * d_h4_d_w12
                self.b4 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h4 * d_h4_d_b4

                # Neuron h5
                self.w13 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h5 * d_h5_d_w13
                self.w14 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h5 * d_h5_d_w14
                self.w15 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h5 * d_h5_d_w15
                self.b5 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_h5 * d_h5_d_b5

                # Neuron hi1
                self.w16 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi1 * d_hi1_d_w16
                self.w17 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi1 * d_hi1_d_w17
                self.w18 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi1 * d_hi1_d_w18
                self.w19 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi1 * d_hi1_d_w19
                self.w20 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi1 * d_hi1_d_w20
                self.b6 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi1 * d_hi1_d_b6

                # Neuron hi2
                self.w21 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi2 * d_hi2_d_w21
                self.w22 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi2 * d_hi2_d_w22
                self.w23 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi2 * d_hi2_d_w23
                self.w24 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi2 * d_hi2_d_w24
                self.w25 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi2 * d_hi2_d_w25
                self.b7 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi2 * d_hi2_d_b7

                # Neuron hi3
                self.w26 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi3 * d_hi3_d_w26
                self.w27 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi3 * d_hi3_d_w27
                self.w28 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi3 * d_hi3_d_w28
                self.w29 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi3 * d_hi3_d_w29
                self.w30 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi3 * d_hi3_d_w30
                self.b8 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi3 * d_hi3_d_b8

                # Neuron hi4
                self.w31 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi4 * d_hi4_d_w31
                self.w32 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi4 * d_hi4_d_w32
                self.w33 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi4 * d_hi4_d_w33
                self.w34 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi4 * d_hi4_d_w34
                self.w35 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi4 * d_hi4_d_w35
                self.b9 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi4 * d_hi4_d_b9

                # Neuron hi5 NEW
                self.w36 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi5 * d_hi5_d_w36
                self.w37 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi5 * d_hi5_d_w37
                self.w38 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi5 * d_hi5_d_w38
                self.w39 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi5 * d_hi5_d_w39
                self.w40 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi5 * d_hi5_d_w40
                self.b10 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_hi5 * d_hi5_d_b10

                # Neuron o1 NEW
                self.w41 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w41
                self.w42 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w42
                self.w43 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w43
                self.w44 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w44
                self.w45 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_w45
                self.b11 -= learn_rate * d_L_d_ypred * d_ypred_d_b11

            # --- Calculate total loss at the end of each epoch
            if epoch % 10 == 0:
                firstlayer = np.apply_along_axis(self.feedforward, 1, data)
                y_preds = np.apply_along_axis(self.feedforward2, 1, firstlayer)
                loss = mse_loss(all_y_trues, y_preds)
                print("Epoch %d loss: %.3f" % (epoch, loss))

# Define dataset
data = np.array([
  [-2, -1, 16],  # Alice
  [25, 6, -5],   # Bob
  [17, 4, 20],   # Charlie
  [-15, -6 ,7], # Diana
])
all_y_trues = np.array([
  1, # Alice
  0, # Bob
  0, # Charlie
  1, # Diana
])

# Train our neural network!
network = OurNeuralNetwork()
network.train(data, all_y_trues)
```

Comment: p.s. there are other methods I just took them out to not make the post too long

Comment: You are missing `)` in the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be missing `(` in previous line:

```
d_ypred_d_h.append(deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1) * (self.wforo1[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1) * self.wforhi1[i] + self.wforo1[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2) * self.wforhi2[i] + self.wforo1[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3) * self.wforhi3[i] + self.wforo1[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4) * self.wforhi4[i] + self.wforo1[4] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5) * self.wforhi5[i])
```

Update the line as given below:

```
d_ypred_d_h.append(deriv_sigmoid(sum_o1) * (self.wforo1[0] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi1) * self.wforhi1[i] + self.wforo1[1] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi2) * self.wforhi2[i] + self.wforo1[2] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi3) * self.wforhi3[i] + self.wforo1[3] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi4) * self.wforhi4[i] + self.wforo1[4] * deriv_sigmoid(sum_hi5) * self.wforhi5[i]))
```